# Exercise about the basis of the coproduct

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

> a) Let $V_{1}, V_{2}, \ldots, V_{k} $ be vector spaces with bases $ B_{1}, \ldots, B_{k}$. Specify a basis of the Cartesian product $ V=V_{1} \times V_{2} \times \cdots \times V_{k} $.
>
> b) Specify a basis of $ \mathbb{R}^{(\mathrm{N})}$.
>
> **Note:** Show that your answer is actually a basis in each case.

**Here is my solution approach:**

(It would be great if someone could have a look at my solution for part a) and help me with part b))

**a)**

$ v=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j}\left(b_{j}\right) \sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} \mu_{i}\left(\beta_{i}\right)\left(b_{j}, \beta_{i}\right)$ of $V_{1}, V_{2}$ because

$v_{1} \in V_{1} \quad v_{1}=\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \lambda_{j}\left(b_{j}\right) b_{j}$

$v_{2} \in V_{2} \quad v_{2}=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{m} \mu_{i}\left(\beta_{i}\right) \beta_{i}$

$\vdots$

$ v_{k} \in V_{k} \quad v_{k}=\underbrace{\left.\sum \limits_{l=1}^{r} \phi_{l}\left(\gamma_{l}\right) \gamma_{l}\right)}_{\text {basis of } V_{k}}$

hence:

$ v=\left(\sum \limits_{j=1}^{n} \Phi_{j}\left(b_{j}\right) b_{j}, \ldots, \sum \limits_{l=1}^{r} \Phi_{l}\left(\gamma_{l}\right) \gamma_{l}\right)=\sum \limits_{\gamma=1}^{n} \cdot \ldots \cdot \sum \limits_{l=1}^{r}\left(\lambda_{j}\left(b_{j}\right) b_{j}, \ldots, \Phi_{l}\left(\gamma_{l}\right) \gamma_{l}\right)$

$=\underbrace{\sum \limits_{\sigma=1} \lambda_{j}\left(b_{j}\right) \cdot \ldots \cdot \sum \limits_{l=1}^{r} \Phi_{l}\left(j_{l}\right) \cdot\left(b_{j}, \ldots, \gamma_{l}\right)}_{\text{Cross product of bases of the vector spaces}}$

**b)**

I know that it's a $\mathbb{N}$-tuple of the bases, but how do I write that down?

Comment: For part  a) you have shown that one element of the product is generated by the set $B_{1}\times\cdots\times B_{k}$ you have to show that they are linearly independent. For part b) Does "N" stand for the number "N" ?

Comment: „N“ means all natural numbers excluding 0.

Comment: In that case, for  $k\geq 1$, $e_{k}$ where you have $1$ in the $k^{th}$position an zero otherwise. I think there is a better way for writing this base.